# No match for operator << in exception handling program

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "NegativeBalanceException.hpp"
#include <memory>

class Account
{
private:
    std::string name;
    double balance;
public:

    Account(std::string name, double balance);
    ~Account() {std::cout <<"Calling Account Destroyer" << std::endl;}
    void get_name() const {std::cout << name << std::endl;}
    void get_balance() const {std::cout << balance << std::endl;}
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Account &account);

};

    Account::Account(std::string name, double balance) 
        : name{name}, balance{balance} {
            if (balance < 0)
            throw NegativeBalanceException();
    }

    std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Account &account) {
        os << "Account Name: " << account.get_name() << "\n" << "Account 
        Balance: " << account.get_balance() << std::endl;
        return os;
    }

int main () {

    std::unique_ptr<Account> Austin;
    try {
        Austin = std::make_unique<Account>("Austin",1000);
        std::cout << *Austin << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const NegativeBalanceException &ex) {
        std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Hello I am a beginner programmer and I am practicing exception handling and I do not know why my overloaded operator << is not working. It won't let me display my data that I want.

Comment: Are `get_name()` and `get_balance()` supposed to return a value, or print to `std::cout`? The functions are used as the former, but written as the later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `get_name()` and `get_balance()` methods are both declared with `void` return values, so your overloaded `operator<<` can't pass them to `os << ...`.  Internally, the methods are doing their own logging to `std::cout`, so you would need to change your `operator<<` accordingly, eg:

```cpp
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Account &account) {
    os << "Account Name: ";
    account.get_name();
    os << "Account Balance: ";
    account.get_balance();
    return os;
}
```

However, this will not work as expected if `os` does not refer to `std::cout`, for example if your `main()` decided to stream the `Account` to a `std::ofstream` instead.

A better option is to change `get_name()` and `get_balance()` to return values instead, and not do their own logging directly:

```cpp
std::string get_name() const { return name; }
double get_balance() const { return balance; }
```

Then your overloaded `operator<<` will work as expected.

Comment: Thank you so much haha I am just still confused on when to use out and return, but yeah it fixed the problem changing it to return. Very much appreciated! Thanks a lot to the others guy for helping as well too.

Answer (score 0):

These

```
void get_name() const {std::cout << name << std::endl;}
void get_balance() const {std::cout << balance << std::endl;}
```

should be written like this

```
std::string get_name() const { return name; }
double get_balance() const { return balance; }
```

Functions which return values are not the same as functions which print values. In your overloaded operator<< you need two functions to **return** the values in the account object, so the operator<< can print them.